# Anonymous pipe access error between C# program and Unity mod

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a mod for the game 'The Forest' which requires data from the game to be sent an external C# process. I am unable to use memory mapped files as the mod needs to be written with .NET Framework 3.5.
I have used the code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication to try achieve IPC via anonymous pipes.

My mod successfully runs the PipeClient process however when the PipeClient attempts to read the data from the pipe I receive a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.` For more information it is specifically when the PipeClient calls `temp = sr.ReadLine()`.

The code from Microsoft works fine on its own and I simply copied the pipe server code into the `Start()` function of class that inherits `MonoBehaviour` in my mod. And I also moved the `PipeClient` build files to the appropriate directory of the game. So how would I get around this access error and establish a proper pipe connection?

Comment: I have absolutely zero experience with this, but if you right click the files in question, are they marked as blocked? E.g., if you download from the Internet you'll get a message under the "Attributes" section regarding it being blocked. Thought 2 is do you need to run the app as an elevated user?

Comment: Ok so running the game in administrator does not fix the problem and the files I've checked: game executable, pipeclient files and my mod's dll, do not have the section regarding it being blocked.

Comment: "the code works fine on its own" how did you test that?

Comment: I created two C# Console App projects in Visual Studio, one PipeClient, the other PipeServer and copied their respective code from the Microsoft example. Then built it and ended up with two .exe files. I copy the build files from the PipeClient to the PipeServer build directory so the PipeServer can actually find the PipeClient.exe process to start. Then when I launch the PipeServer.exe I get a PipeServer.exe console window where I can type stuff that is read by the server and then sent to the client who then echos it in the same console window i.e. both the .exe programs work with each other.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem, when I launch the game, it opens a console window labeled PipeClient.exe instead of PipeServer.exe like in my test console apps. However, I have UseShellExecute for the pipeclient process set to false in my mod, but then again the game isn't just another console app. So maybe I need to build some special unity app instead of a simple console app for the pipeclient? Does anyone know what type of app the pipeclient should be so that unity can properly launch it as a child process?